# Using Nullable variables with Math.Pow

Tags: c#

I have defined a few variables as Nullable, however when passed to Math.Pow, they do not work as Math.Pow seems to only work with `double` and not `double?`. Is there any way around this?

```
        public Nullable<double> d = null;

        public Nullable<double> c = null;

        public Nullable<double> s = null;

        public Nullable<double> m = null;

        public Nullable<double> radius = null;

        public Nullable<double> x1 = null;

        public Nullable<double> y1 = null;

        public Nullable<double> x2 = null;

        public Nullable<double> y2 = null;

private void Run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //implement TryParse
        d = double.Parse(this.downwind.Text);
        c = double.Parse(this.crosswind.Text);
        s = double.Parse(this.maxcross.Text);
        m = double.Parse(this.offset.Text);
        radius = double.Parse(this.rad.Text);
        x1 = double.Parse(this.x1coord.Text);
        y1 = double.Parse(this.y1coord.Text);
        x2 = double.Parse(this.x2coord.Text);
        y2 = double.Parse(this.y2coord.Text);


        double? xdiff = x1 - x2;
        double? ydiff = y1 - y2;
        double? xmax = x1 + m;

        if (xdiff.HasValue == true && ydiff.HasValue == true)
        {
            htarget = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(xdiff,2) + Math.Pow(ydiff,2));
        }
}
```

Comment: `Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow((double)xdiff,2) + Math.Pow((double)ydiff,2));`

Comment: Thanks it worked!!

Comment: Or, you could write functions that actually handle nullable doubles. But you'd have to define how null is propagated through the function. For example Sqrt(null) would be null,  as would Pow(null. 2.0), but Pow(1.0, null) might be 10.0, or 0.0 (or null or NaN). Just casting a nullable value type to a non nullable version is dangerous

Comment: I would like to try this out @Flydog57. Any resource where I could read more in to this? I'm not aware of this. Thank you

Comment: Well, the rules in the SQL language are that anything that touches a NULL becomes a null (for example, concatenating a string and NULL becomes NULL).  In addition, nothing is equal to NULL (example, if A and B are both NULL, then "where A=B" evaluates the "A=B" part as false).  In C#, if a and b are both null, then then compare as equal.  For the most part (but not always), operations on null-ish things in C# throw  You get to make up your own rules (I've never seen anyone expound (/philosophize) on the nature of null propogation).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `xdiff.Value` and `ydiff.Value` to get the primitive.